# HTML of a parsed page

Tags: java, parsing, cobra

I am using Cobra parsing engine and I wish to get HTML code of an already parsed page (e.g. after javascripts executions). Is it possible to do? Cobra may be replaced with another open-source java web parser if needed.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, Cobra actually seems to do it: [Example of Usage](http://lobobrowser.org/cobra/java-html-parser.jsp)

It actually gives you a tree of HTML DOM-Nodes. You can use [HTMLWriter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLWriter.html) to get the HTML-Text if you prefer, but if you're interested in some specific portion of it, use XPath, it's much cleaner than to search in the HTML-String.